# how to make a shadow box with gradient color ?

Tags: css, shadowbox

Hi i trying manny time but i can't created this. 
I should be as like this below images in pure css without any images

[image]

and now i want to used only single div .

Thanks advanced .

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Comment: shadow box as in box shadow, if yes, you could do something like `box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #aaa`

Comment: I always like to try and solve as much as possible without images and with the new CSS3 gradients and shadows a lot of things are possible without them. This, however, I don't think is. Particularly the "tilting" shadows and the fold effect.

Comment: If you want this in a single div, you're going to have to use an image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see you can make this in css3 easily you can use the before and after Pseudo Class Selectors for right and left side image curve and in the middle you can play with css3 for shadow box & gradient color etc....and it will come in only one div.

I hope you got it the idea what i am trying to explain you.....

see the demo for better understanding:- http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9D5/37/

Answer (score 0):

you could try to play around with this one:

[css3gen](http://css3generator.com/)

Comment: but i want to complete in single div

Comment: it's not possible without an image